# difference between vector initializations?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

and

```
std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

?

Should I prefer one over the other in any particular circumstance?

Comment: ***Should I prefer one over the other in any particular circumstance?*** I expect both to yield the exact same code when optimized. You may want to look at https://godbolt.org/ for confirmation.

Comment: Semantically, there is a slight difference: the first constructs a temporary vector, and uses that to initialise `v` (i.e. it does copy-list-initialization) and the second constructs `v` from an intializer list (it does direct-list-initialization). Practically (e.g. in terms of emitted code when optimisation is setting) the two examples are the same.  With types other than `std::vector` (e.g. with a `delete`d copy constructor) the approaches can have different outcomes.  For consistency, I would therefore use the second.